# Error 500 after installing Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, ssh

I have a Laravel project (version 5.3) that works well on my localhost (wampserver).

Now I want to run this project on a subdomain of my website.I have ssh root access and a vps user access (not admin - with Directadmin - PHP version 5.4).

I uploaded project files to my server but when I try to see the project result , it gives me a 500 error.

I have tried to change 'storage' folder permissions , so I read [this answer](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel5-gives-blank-page-with-500-status-code-on-apache-fedora22/replies/98874) , but when I run "chchon" ssh command , I get errors like this :

```
can't apply partial context to unlabeled file ...
```

also , I have tested Laravel with version 4.2 and it worked well.

Does any boy have idea ?? Thanks

Comment: is there anything in storage/log/laravel.log file?

Comment: @usrNotFound   I don't see anything new. I think Laravel doesn't run , So there is no new log

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have SELinux enabled, you can set permissions simply with `chmod` or set the owner of the storage directory with `chown` to the web server's user. (which is probably www-data)
Try to run `sudo chown -R www-data storage` in the project directory

Answer (score 0):

Try all this

```
// first delete the vendor folder inside your project root, then run
 composer install     

// laravel generates log file there
 sudo chmod -R 777 storage/logs

// laravel cache the files here
 sudo chmod -R 777 bootstrap/cache 

// vendor folder, where laravel saves their dependencies
 sudo chmod -R 777 storage/ vendor/

// generate a application key
 php artisan key:generate
```

This might help :)

Comment: Thanks for your help.
When I ran "php artisan key:generate" , I got the following error :
`PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in /home/samt/domains/WEBSITE/public_html/SUB/artisan on line 31
`
Also when I run "sudo chmod .." commands , I get this :
`chmod: missing operand after `bootstrap/cache'
`

Comment: When I try to install composer I get some errors like this :

`PHP Warning:  putenv() has been disabled ...
 Problem 3
    - Installation request for laravel/framework v5.3.31 -> satisfiable by larav                                                  el/framework[v5.3.31].
`

Do you think the problem is the server php version ?
As I said before Laravel 4.2 works well !

Comment: Yeah. I think so, some of the package in composer.json need some extra extension or something.  see this link for put env https://laravel.io/forum/04-16-2015-disabled-function-putenv